Open debugger doesn't work in React Native 0.74
I have created a new project with latest version but open debugger is not working for me due to which i am facing a lot of issue in debugging.
I have tried already following but Xcode crashes with it.
npx react-native start --experimental-debugger

Debugger doesn't work and Xcode crashes every time it starts.

You can fix this issue by add your project configuration in following steps.

In Chrome browser window, navigation to chrome://inspect
Use the Configure button to add the server address (typically localhost:8081)
You should see now "Hermes React Native" target with an inspect click. Click this to open debugger.

Reference: https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#opening-the-debugger
Thanks

Good news from React native Team. React native 0.76.0 stable version is released now on Oct 24,2024 which a completely newly best written a new debugging experience in React native.
